Importing external python files depending on execution context
I'm trying to seperate out my code into other files that contain functions etc that I can reuse. The issue I have is how I have to call these functions depending on whether it's part of a package or not (it's context).
When it's not part of a package (during dev), I'm loading all my python scripts in the scene (via the scripting workspace). I can access my functions via a function = bpy.data.texts["functions.py"].as_module() statement and calling function.function_name() and all works well.
However, this approach doesn't work when I distribute it as a package.
In this situation, a __all__ = ["functions"] statement is required in my init.py file and then a from . functions import * to import all functions. In this situation I just call function_name() and again, it works.
This is messy enough, but the real issue is what I need to call depends on the context. So when not a package, I have to call function.function_name() but when in a package it has to be just function_name()
Surely there must be a nicer way than this?
Thanks for any help!

What exactly is the purpose of the functions? I get the feeling this an XY Problem. Tell us what your end goal is, not how to debug your solution, because it's possible there's a much easier way to do what you're trying to do that involves an entirely different approach.

Several reasons. Firstly, I'd like to reduce the size of my code by breaking it into more manageable pieces and secondly (and hopefully) share functions across different packages.

You can use __package__ or __spec__ in an if statement to support both import X and from . import X, but it is better to stick to using your addon as a module. So from my_addon import utils if you want to use the addon from outside, to check something in the text editor, but inside it is from . import utils.
I recommend you to use VSCode plus fake-bpy-module for the addon development. To edit any addon with VSCode you open the addon's folder as a workspace or a folder. To implement reloading the addon without restarting Blender, see this answer or use Blender Development extension.

Many thanks, fake-bpy-module resolved this.
